# DarthNyan отсутствует в файле sudoers

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Привет. 
Пишет, что меня нет в sudoers, но я там есть.

```
DarthNyan@PC:~$ sudo -u postgres psql
sudo: setresuid() [1000, 113, 1000] -> [-1, 0, -1]: Операция не позволена         
sudo: unable to set runas group vector: Операция не позволена                     
sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, -1, 0): Операция не позволена                       
sudo: не удаётся открыть /var/run/sudo/ts/DarthNyan: Отказано в доступе           
[sudo] пароль для DarthNyan:                                                      
sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, -1, 0): Операция не позволена                       
DarthNyan отсутствует в файле sudoers. Данное действие будет занесено в 
журнал.
DarthNyan@PC:~$ cat /etc/group | grep DarthNyan
adm:x:4:syslog,DarthNyancdrom:x:24:DarthNyan 
sudo:x:27:DarthNyan
audio:x:29:DarthNyan
dip:x:30:DarthNyan
plugdev:x:46:DarthNyan
DarthNyan:x:1000:
DarthNyan@PC:~$ 



DarthNyan@PC:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
[sudo] пароль для DarthNyan:
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
# Host alias specification
# User alias specification
# Cmnd alias specification
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL     
DarthNyan       ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
DarthNyan@PC:~$
```

Comment: А что, собственно, в /etc/sudoers?

Comment: @Hellseher прикрепил

Comment: Во-первых, не используйте *cat* без причины, а то пословица получится. Во-вторых, удалите строку со своим именем из *sudoers*. В-третьих, не стоит использовать большие буквы в учётной записи пользователя. И наконец в-четвёртых, вы же файл вывели с помощью *sudo*, что не так?

Comment: @0andriy пожалуйста не оставляйте свои сообщения на этом сайте, лучше в принципе ничего не комментируйте.

Comment: Какой-то странный у вас троллинг получается...